# nodejs child process signal handling

Tags: node.js

I'v got a daemon child process (Linux) spawned from the server via **child_process.spawn(...)**.

I can kill it with **p.kill()** command and the child process dies fine.
However, when I send *USR* signals to the child process - let's say **p.kill("SIGUSR1")** - prior to killing it **p.kill("SIGKILL")** the child process gets the **USR1** signal, but, surprisingly, the subsequent **SIGKILL** never gets to the child(!?). Also, **exit** event of the child process is not called as well.

Is there anything I miss about signal handling in node?

Cheers

Comment: Can you include your `SIGUSR1` signal handling code?

Comment: @sarnold: it's a simple shell script: trap "echo 'GOT IT!'" SIGUSR1

Comment: Found it! It's a bug: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1035

process(child's pid,signal) - that works fine multiple times

Comment: Don't add "Solved" to the title.  Post the solution as an answer to your own question and accept it.

Comment: Excellent! Don't forget to add that as an answer as soon as The Stack lets you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have just found it :) It's a bug: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1035

Calling **process.kill(pid,signal)** works multiple times.

Cheers